# Amazon S3 SignatureDoesNotMatch Debugging Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, base64

I've been at this for about 6 hours and cannot get it it working. A user uploads a file on the front end, then this code processes the image being uploaded via FormData.  Node/Express is serving up the front end (Angular).

**Here is the error:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>

<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>

<AWSAccessKeyId>mysecretkey</AWSAccessKeyId>

<StringToSign>eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjA1MC0wMS0wMVQwMDowMDowMFoiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJjaXJydXNvcHMtcGhvdG9tYW5hZ2VyIn0sWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsIiRrZXkiLCIiXSx7ImFjbCI6InByaXZhdGUifSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJENvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIsIiJdXX0=</StringToSign>

<SignatureProvided>ICFCBXDg5GRnAHc0hNQ12337VVE</SignatureProvided>

<RequestId>469B3A46259C43C4</RequestId>

<HostId>3nUe+3KguKehzLv9lnpfM4jbv5tb3Ek5ArbB1HIZ7ZYGQtkUa+CsSWS9kWQzqOw0zOOC+1nFgC8=</HostId></Error>
```

**Request Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryzIhthrmi6BGC8P1l
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

images/1437203969527143ac1e2-20ac-473f-e00f-740b1c5e0451
------WebKitFormBoundaryzIhthrmi6BGC8P1l
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"

MYAWSACCESSKEYWASHERE
------WebKitFormBoundaryzIhthrmi6BGC8P1l
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"

private
------WebKitFormBoundaryzIhthrmi6BGC8P1l
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"

eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjA1MC0wMS0wMVQwMDowMDowMFoiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJjaXJydXNvcHMtcGhvdG9tYW5hZ2VyIn0sWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsIiRrZXkiLCIiXSx7ImFjbCI6InByaXZhdGUifSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJENvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIsIiJdXX0=
------WebKitFormBoundaryzIhthrmi6BGC8P1l
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

ICFCBXDg5GRnAHc0hNQ12337VVE
------WebKitFormBoundaryzIhthrmi6BGC8P1l
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

image/png
------WebKitFormBoundaryzIhthrmi6BGC8P1l
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

images/1437203969527143ac1e2-20ac-473f-e00f-740b1c5e0451
------WebKitFormBoundaryzIhthrmi6BGC8P1l
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="mario.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryzIhthrmi6BGC8P1l--
```

**Javascript**

```
var URL_S3 = "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/"

var POLICY_JSON = {
    "expiration": "2050-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "conditions": [
        {
            "bucket": "mybucket"
        },
    ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
        {
            "acl": "private"
        },
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]
  ]
};


var secret = 'mysecretkey'
var policyBase64 = Security.base64_encode(JSON.stringify(POLICY_JSON));
var signature = Security.b64_hmac_sha1(secret, policyBase64);
Security.b64_hmac_sha1(secret, policyBase64);

Upload.upload({
        url: URL_S3, //S3 upload url including bucket name
        method: 'POST',
        fields: {
            key: key, // the key to store the file on S3, could be file name or customized
            AWSAccessKeyId: secret,
            acl: 'private', // sets the access to the uploaded file in the bucket: private or public 
            policy: policyBase64, // base64-encoded json policy (see article below)
            signature: signature, // base64-encoded signature based on policy string (see article below)
            "Content-Type": fileType != '' ? fileType : 'application/octet-stream', // content type of the file (NotEmpty)
            filename: key // this is needed for Flash polyfill IE8-9
        },
        file: photo,
    });


app.factory('Security', function () {

var Security = function () {
    /*
     * A JavaScript implementation of the Secure Hash Algorithm, SHA-1, as defined
     * in FIPS PUB 180-1
     * Version 2.1 Copyright Paul Johnston 2000 - 2002.
     * Other contributors: Greg Holt, Andrew Kepert, Ydnar, Lostinet
     * Distributed under the BSD License
     * See http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5 for details.
     */

    /*
     * Configurable variables. You may need to tweak these to be compatible with
     * the server-side, but the defaults work in most cases.
     */

    var hexcase = 0; /* hex output format. 0 - lowercase; 1 - uppercase        */
    var b64pad = ""; /* base-64 pad character. "=" for strict RFC compliance   */
    var chrsz = 8; /* bits per input character. 8 - ASCII; 16 - Unicode      */

    /*
     * These are the functions you'll usually want to call
     * They take string arguments and return either hex or base-64 encoded strings
     */
    function hex_sha1(s) {
        return binb2hex(core_sha1(str2binb(s), s.length * chrsz));
    }

    function b64_sha1(s) {
        return binb2b64(core_sha1(str2binb(s), s.length * chrsz));
    }

    function str_sha1(s) {
        return binb2str(core_sha1(str2binb(s), s.length * chrsz));
    }

    function hex_hmac_sha1(key, data) {
        return binb2hex(core_hmac_sha1(key, data));
    }

    this.b64_hmac_sha1 = function (key, data) {
        return binb2b64(core_hmac_sha1(key, data));
    }

    function str_hmac_sha1(key, data) {
        return binb2str(core_hmac_sha1(key, data));
    }

    /*
     * Perform a simple self-test to see if the VM is working
     */
    function sha1_vm_test() {
        return hex_sha1("abc") == "a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d";
    }

    /*
     * Calculate the SHA-1 of an array of big-endian words, and a bit length
     */
    function core_sha1(x, len) {
        /* append padding */
        x[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << (24 - len % 32);
        x[((len + 64 >> 9) << 4) + 15] = len;

        var w = Array(80);
        var a = 1732584193;
        var b = -271733879;
        var c = -1732584194;
        var d = 271733878;
        var e = -1009589776;

        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16) {
            var olda = a;
            var oldb = b;
            var oldc = c;
            var oldd = d;
            var olde = e;

            for (var j = 0; j < 80; j++) {
                if (j < 16) w[j] = x[i + j];
                else w[j] = rol(w[j - 3] ^ w[j - 8] ^ w[j - 14] ^ w[j - 16], 1);
                var t = safe_add(safe_add(rol(a, 5), sha1_ft(j, b, c, d)),
                    safe_add(safe_add(e, w[j]), sha1_kt(j)));
                e = d;
                d = c;
                c = rol(b, 30);
                b = a;
                a = t;
            }

            a = safe_add(a, olda);
            b = safe_add(b, oldb);
            c = safe_add(c, oldc);
            d = safe_add(d, oldd);
            e = safe_add(e, olde);
        }
        return Array(a, b, c, d, e);

    }

    /*
     * Perform the appropriate triplet combination function for the current
     * iteration
     */
    function sha1_ft(t, b, c, d) {
        if (t < 20) return (b & c) | ((~b) & d);
        if (t < 40) return b ^ c ^ d;
        if (t < 60) return (b & c) | (b & d) | (c & d);
        return b ^ c ^ d;
    }

    /*
     * Determine the appropriate additive constant for the current iteration
     */
    function sha1_kt(t) {
        return (t < 20) ? 1518500249 : (t < 40) ? 1859775393 :
            (t < 60) ? -1894007588 : -899497514;
    }

    /*
     * Calculate the HMAC-SHA1 of a key and some data
     */
    function core_hmac_sha1(key, data) {
        var bkey = str2binb(key);
        if (bkey.length > 16) bkey = core_sha1(bkey, key.length * chrsz);

        var ipad = Array(16),
            opad = Array(16);
        for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            ipad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x36363636;
            opad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
        }

        var hash = core_sha1(ipad.concat(str2binb(data)), 512 + data.length * chrsz);
        return core_sha1(opad.concat(hash), 512 + 160);
    }

    /*
     * Add integers, wrapping at 2^32. This uses 16-bit operations internally
     * to work around bugs in some JS interpreters.
     */
    function safe_add(x, y) {
        var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
        var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
        return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
    }

    /*
     * Bitwise rotate a 32-bit number to the left.
     */
    function rol(num, cnt) {
        return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt));
    }

    /*
     * Convert an 8-bit or 16-bit string to an array of big-endian words
     * In 8-bit function, characters >255 have their hi-byte silently ignored.
     */
    function str2binb(str) {
        var bin = Array();
        var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz)
            bin[i >> 5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (24 - i % 32);
        return bin;
    }

    /*
     * Convert an array of big-endian words to a string
     */
    function binb2str(bin) {
        var str = "";
        var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < bin.length * 32; i += chrsz)
            str += String.fromCharCode((bin[i >> 5] >>> (24 - i % 32)) & mask);
        return str;
    }

    /*
     * Convert an array of big-endian words to a hex string.
     */
    function binb2hex(binarray) {
        var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
        var str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++) {
            str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i >> 2] >> ((3 - i % 4) * 8 + 4)) & 0xF) +
                hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i >> 2] >> ((3 - i % 4) * 8)) & 0xF);
        }
        return str;
    }

    /*
     * Convert an array of big-endian words to a base-64 string
     */
    function binb2b64(binarray) {
        var tab = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
        var str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i += 3) {
            var triplet = (((binarray[i >> 2] >> 8 * (3 - i % 4)) & 0xFF) << 16) | (((binarray[i + 1 >> 2] >> 8 * (3 - (i + 1) % 4)) & 0xFF) << 8) | ((binarray[i + 2 >> 2] >> 8 * (3 - (i + 2) % 4)) & 0xFF);
            for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (i * 8 + j * 6 > binarray.length * 32) str += b64pad;
                else str += tab.charAt((triplet >> 6 * (3 - j)) & 0x3F);
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    function update() {
        document.f.result.value =
            b64_hmac_sha1(document.f.seed.value,
                document.f.parameter.value)
            .substr(0, 8);
    }



    this.base64_encode = function (data) {
        var b64 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
        var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
            ac = 0,
            enc = '',
            tmp_arr = [];

        if (!data) {
            return data;
        }

        do { // pack three octets into four hexets
            o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
            o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
            o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);

            bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 8 | o3;

            h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
            h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
            h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
            h4 = bits & 0x3f;

            // use hexets to index into b64, and append result to encoded string
            tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
        } while (i < data.length);

        enc = tmp_arr.join('');

        var r = data.length % 3;

        return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3);
    };

    this.guid = function () {
        function s4() {
            return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                .toString(16)
                .substring(1);
        }
        return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
            s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
    }

};

return new Security;

});
```

Comment: There's a lot of noise in your question, and I would suggest that you need to try to pinpoint where the process is breaking down.  The error gives you the string to sign.  That is not necessarily the string you actually signed, it's the string you *should have tried to sign*.  Verify that you are coming up with a matching string in your code, to see if the problem is before after that step.

Comment: I'd recommend using the relevant Amazon SDK to do signing and interacting with S3. Signing non-trivial requests, especially if you need to support newer regions that require version 4 signing, is complex. The JavaScript SDK has a simple upload facility that will perform multi-part uploads.

Comment: @jarmod i went ahead and used the amazon sdk and handled this with node on the backend - worked out of the box.

Comment: @Spentak Good to hear. There are other options too, for example having your server return time-limited session credentials or a time-limited S3 URL to the browser client that would allow the client to upload directly to S3, without having to proxy through your node server. But it sounds like you have a good solution.